# Implement a 2x1 MUX using 1x2 decoder

Tags: multiplexer, decoder

I need to implement a 2x1 MUX using a 1x2 decoder(We may also use 2 AND gates and 1 OR gate). I've made a start, but I'm kind of stuck. I thought, hey, I've taken a function table and implemented it using decoders, I'll give that a try. So I took the function table of a 2x1 MUX, and tried to implement it using a decoder. I think I've run into a problem though, I don't think a 1x2 Decoder is enough because I'll always have an input of 1 or 0 through my select input for my Decoder, and this will output a 1 or 0. And I can't find a way to make those work for my MUX. Can anyone show me how to do this? And suggest a method for solving these types of questions (i.e. Implement this Module using another Module. I've been exposed to Decoders,MUX, and deMUX)

Answer (score 0):

The decoder alone is not enough. The decoder can give you a couple of enable outputs, which you can use to select which input to forward. You will need to use those two and gates and the or gate to actually switch between the inputs.